# How to change base_url in drupal 7, fail to find answer online

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to change base_url on my drupal 7 website, but failed to do it and google a lot, still could not solve it .

I am running localhost/drupal "on my local server. but I want to run it like 
" localhost ".  ( sorry I have to get rid of http://, otherwise it doesnot let me post)

How to get rid of folder in the url. I know I need to change $base_url on sites/default/setting.php to

$base_url = 'localhost';  // NO trailing slash! ( sorry I have to get rid of http://, otherwise it doesnot let me post)

And in the .htaccess file I am so confused what should I change. People online have their own solution, some said they work , some could not . Could someone give me some suggesttion ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this has to do with where you have placed your files.
In your file system, remove the 'drupal' directory and place all the files within that at /var/www/html  ... instead of /var/www/html/drupal, if that's how it is currently set up.

Comment: I am running XMAP on mac .. I do not think that's works.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain; I've had this trouble myself before and I believe I had to alter both the settings.php and the htaccess (but try one at a time to begin with). I'm fairly sure that the section below in your .htaccess is what needs changing (just remove the hash from in front of the RewriteBase line). If you're unsure of what you're doing, make a copy of your .htaccess as htaccess.txt and then you can always switch back over if things get nasty.

```
# Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
# VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
# For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
# modify the following line:
# RewriteBase /drupal
```

Comment: I did what you said. I uncooment # RewriteBase /drupal  line. When I type localhost on my url, it redirect to localhost/xampp , and if I type localhost/drupal the css style are gone.. only context show up on my page..

Comment: Have you also un-commented out and correctly set the base_url variable in your settings.php file? That should sort out the file path issue you're getting with your css.

Comment: in the setting file I set to

$base_url = 'localhost'; // NO trailing slash! ( there is  http:// in front of 'localhost'

Answer (score 0):

I just realised that what you need is a re-write rule in an .htaccess file within your root folder (not the one that's inside the drupal folder). First, undo any edits you've already made, then create an .htaccess file in the same folder that contains your drupal folder and in it, add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /drupal [L]
```

That should send any traffic from the root into the drupal file structure. If you get issues with strange css, or urls that include the /drupal path, you'll need to revisit the other options in the /drupal/.htaccess file and your settings.php file in order to get it all working correctly.

However, going down this route, you may as well just copy all the files and folders into the root directory anyway (as the first answer suggested), assuming you're not going to be running multiple sites. If you do want to be testing multiple sites, you can just change the  RewriteRul above to whatever site directory you're wanting to test in future.

Comment: It is working on my home page when I type localhost but other content page could not show up like contact, .....only the home page...the error is "Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster. " ...So I think there is routing I should added onto the .htaccess file you just gave it to me